# Docker containers onlys up when access the host with ssh

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, containers, production

I have two containers it was builded with command > docker-compose up --build -d.
All containers build normally and stays up, but when I leave the machine the containers stays up at least 2 hours until que he drops again.

This containers is running an API in PHP LARAVEL Framework and a nginx reverse proxy.

[Docker Image Started as 46Hours ago and UP 2 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1grXm.png)

When I start the application and leave the machine where Docker is installed, it is in max two hours running. If I access the machine via ssh and then after that access the application and it is running without the need to do a docker-compose up. And the api was written in Laravel PHP with a Nginx container making a reverse Proxy.

What do I have to do to make these containers stand up as a productive environment?

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "stays up"? How is this related to Composer?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I put more information, thanks.

Comment: "What do I have to do to make these containers stand up as a productive environment?" - what does that mean? How do you start the container? Does the log contain any information? And how is this related to Composer, PHP's package manager?

Comment: "What do I have to do to make these containers stand up as a productive environment?"
Application running without stops
"How do you start the container? "
docker-compose build up -d

"Does the log contain any information?"
Only log about connection handlers

Answer (score 0):

There is a command that can help you when it goes down or stops:

```
sudo docker run --restart unless-stopped --name <Name you want to use> <Name of your container>
```

> don't use these  <> in your command

after doing this anytime that container is down it will restart the container for you automatically.

I think this trick is really useful when you have multiple containers running, and helpful when you want to update the server packages too.

Comment: Thanks tor the answer, '>' in command it was a mistype, but i run my containers with the docker-compose and no have a --restart unless-stopped parameter.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and initiative.
 I managed to find the problem. I had configured my server with Docker and used the dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install script to use docker other than root. I thought it had something to do with Laravel, but no. Thank you.